# How to write into rails log from a job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I am facing an issue concerning logs. I built a rails app using ActiveJob with Sidekiq.

I want to write an entry into rails logs from a background job.

Usually, when I want to write an entry, I do something like this (in a controller for instance):

```
Rails.logger.fatal "BIG ISSUE!!!"
```

So I wanted to do the same but this time, in a background job:

```
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    Rails.logger.fatal"FATAL TEST"
  end
end
```

However nothing is written in the rails logs. Can you explain me why? And how to make this work?

Comment: What's your loglevel set to in the environment you're running Sidekiq in? It could be an issue around it running in a environment that has logging turned off or the log level set high (though fatal should always come through). Can you add some debugging to your sidekiq job to have it emit the log level, the environment, and if its dev, the filename it thinks to write to?


`puts Rails.env;`
`puts Rails.logger.level;`
`puts Rails.logger.instance_variable_get('@logdev').instance_variable_get('@dev').path`

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq logs will go to the /var/log/syslog to redirect check out this article https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Logging